# How to guarantee the execution of an event in java

Tags: java

I have two classes, the first is updating data in a database and the second sends an email to inform user about the update.

```
updateTable(){
   // update table code
}

sendEmail(){
   // send email 
}
```

I use them in a function that executes them both once the event is triggered.

```
function(){
    updateTable();
    sendEmail();
}
```

My question is how can I be sure that the email was sent when the update was executed successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't guarantee that a mail was sent successfully. There can be several issues with sending the mail that are simply out of the scope of your application.

What you *can* do is roll back the changes if the sending of the mail fails. I suggest you look into [database transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

With transactions you can run a query, do some other actions (or other queries) and either commit the changes or roll them back when you know whether everything ran successfully or not.